# How do I find a ASP.NET hosting company that supports SQL Server with CLR enabled?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, hosting, sqlclr

So I developed a web application in ASP.NET and SQL Server 2008. Part of the SQL code I implemented as a .NET assembly (instead of t-sql) because it is performing intense calculations that are better written in C#.

Now I am ready to deploy my application, but I am stuck looking for a hosting company that allows this. Scratch out Discount ASP ([see this forum post](http://community.discountasp.net/showthread.php?t=4464&highlight=assembly)). I tried emailing other hosting companies and I either get no reply or they say they will not support it.

Any recommendations? What's the big deal with having CLR enabled in SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is disabled by default and most shared hosts will be reluctant to enable it because of the potential added security issues. You could post a request to webhostingtalk. Some options:

Amazon EC2 with SQL Server or SQL Server Express Edition, a VPS ([1and1](http://order.1and1.com/xml/order/VpsWindows) has a pretty good deal right now) running Express Edition, or of course your own dedicated box

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'm the only one with this problem. For now I decided to just port my code to t-sql until I am ready to move to dedicated server environment.

Comment: Can you precisely tell what security issues can arise when CLR is enabled? I have an impression that this is the myth that is told everywhere but without any reasonable explanation.

Answer (score 0):

On Amazon EC2 you get your own dedicated box, so you are free to enable / install what you see fit.  You could configure a vanilla server then install the SQL Enterprise eval if you wanted.

Answer (score -1):

Your own dedicated box with SQL Express may be your best bet.