# Are there any security issues with enabling CLR on SQL SERVER 2005?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, security

I am toying with the idea of enabling CLR on my SQL server, using `EXEC sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1`

However, I am sharing my database server with several other developers and their projects.  I've heard vaguely that their might be [security issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992618/how-do-i-find-a-asp-net-hosting-company-that-supports-sql-server-with-clr-enabled) with enabling this.

Does anyone know what these issues might be?  Is CLR safe to use on SQL Server?

Answer (score 3):

**No, SQLCLR code can’t do anything more in a database than an equivalent T-SQL code module running under the same security context.**

This was and currently is the most misunderstood security claim in all of SQL Server (especially 2012 onwards), which can break UI connectivity to [SCCM databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sccm/core/plan-design/configs/support-for-sql-server-versions), the flagship ETL deployment model SSISDB (requires CLR), because a 3rd party security tool inheriting CIS benchmarks (DBProtect primarily) which also incorrectly flags SQL Server collation coefficients via 2000 even if the server is not running 2000, falsely directing DBAs to rebuild master and forever crippling their environment and applications as case sensitive if nobody speaks up on the finding. **CLR is not a security risk**, it allows for flagship enhancements (post SQL Server 2012) to security in multiple regards via RDP and file system right mitigation and SSIS code management e.g. SSISDB, which is likely to impact every 90% of SQL Server shops, including HA solutions built to not rely on a single SAN.

A side note regarding DBAs who are simply averse to CLR it because it can be "difficult to troubleshoot if made badly" - it is not primarily inside DBA purview to troubleshoot senior .NET developer code, if you hire bad DBAs they too can be difficult to troubleshoot (see above via collation). Further, the majority of people leveraging CLR are doing so for the flagship functions and have little or nothing to do with writing CLR code (although [script tasks in SSIS leverage this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27863/calling-a-net-method-in-a-sql-server-script) to a degree), and have much more to do with SSISDB and using availability groups across SANs. DBAs who dislike this functionality should jump into a time warp and hit stasis mode for the year 2008. This is written from a full-stack BI/DBA perspective, not from a somewhat myopic sys internals vantage point.

Further, [Availability Groups utilize CLR](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/103553/clr-assemblies-and-sql-server-availability-groups), causing an error if CLR is not enabled. More information also vetted on [Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj899851.aspx)

**Both both Availability Groups and SSISDB are flagship features of modern SQL Server environments.**

Currently, by enabling CLR and deploying SSIS packages via the SSISDB, you can mitigate file system organization mismanagement and clutter, gain inherited backup maintenance plans and even TDE, and actually drastically lower the need for RDP to troubleshoot an SSIS package.

Ask your DBA if he cares so much about security why Mixed Mode Authentication is set on, no SSL certs for SSMS or SSRS or Excel clients, TDE is not enabled, and lack of auditing or even logging successful and failed logins.

http://www.codemag.com/article/0603031

To enable CLR simply run

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

Comment: From the fact that SQL CLR was unceremoniously removed from Azure for security reasons and SQL Server 2017 introduces a new option CLR strict security which is enabled by default then it is pretty clear there are potential security issues and you should not allow unreviewed CLR code to be deployed.

Comment: So was the SQL Agent in Azure - your assertion has no basis or citation.

Comment: Did you look at the article on strict security? It states `CLR assembly created with PERMISSION_SET = SAFE may be able to access external system resources, call unmanaged code, and acquire sysadmin privilege` - escalating privileges to sysadmin is a pretty clear security issue and contradicts the assertion in your answer that `SQLCLR code can’t do anything more in a database than an equivalent T-SQL code module running under the same security context`

Comment: "running under the same security context" - no it does not.

Answer (score 1):

I am with Squillman on this one; unfortunately, the answer is not as simple as a “yes” or “no”.

Enabling CLR on the server enables hosting user-defined CLR modules on your server, which opens a non-trivial set of possibilities to create custom modules & data types, but it also opens a significant attack surface area on your server.

There are further considerations to take:

- Who has privileged permissions on the DB? Do you trust all other
  people who may be able to create assemblies on your SQL Server? If
  not, be aware that they will be able to host CLR code on your server,
  something I would not recommend.
- Other settings on the server, including ownership of DBs & the
  Trustworthy bit setting on the    database. The following article has
  more detail on this topic:
  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2007/12/03/the-trustworhy-bit-database-property-in-sql-server-2005/
- .Net itself is not bug free. While hosting CLR code is a much better 
  idea than hosting eXtended stored Procedures (XPs), there is always a
  risk of a security vulnerability within the .Net framework itself, in
  which case what would typically be a safe CLR module hosted in SQL
  Server could become an attack vector to gain control of your SQL
  Server process. It doesn’t happen often, but you have to ever be vigilant 
  and act accordingly when it happens.

I hope this helps,

-Raul Garcia

SQL Security

Answer (score 0):

From the fact that SQL CLR [was unceremoniously removed from Azure for security reasons](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/04/breaking-news-literally-sql-clr-support-removed-azure-sql-db/) and SQL Server 2017 introduces a new option [CLR strict security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/clr-strict-security) which is enabled by default then it is pretty clear there are potential security issues and you should not allow unreviewed CLR code to be deployed.

the strict security link states

> CLR assembly created with PERMISSION_SET = SAFE may be able to access
>   external system resources, call unmanaged code, and acquire sysadmin
>   privilege

One of the comments on the linked post above mentions

> Many “.NET Security Updates” running through Windows Update are cases
>   where someone could escape from the .NET sandbox using safe code. Very
>   many such cases over the years.

Moreover

[SQL Server Guidance to protect against speculative execution side-channel vulnerabilities](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4073225/guidance-for-sql-server) specifically lists "SQL CLR assemblies" in the "Untrusted SQL Server extensibility mechanisms" section.